# How can I generate a new row and column output from a nested key in a JSONB field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Field JSONB Structure:**

```
{
  ...
  "field_name": "field_value",
  "columns": [
    ...
    {
        "nested_key_1": "nested_value_1"
        "nested_key_2": "nested_value_2"
    },
    {
        "nested_key_1": "nested_value_1"
        "nested_key_2": "nested_value_2"
    },
  ],
}
```

**Desired Output:**

```
----------------------------------------------
|   |  nested_key_1     |   "nested_key_2"  |
----------------------------------------------
| 1 |  nested_value_1   |   nested_value_2  |
----------------------------------------------
| 2 |  nested_value_1   |   nested_value_2  |
----------------------------------------------
```

One of my attempts to achieve this:

```
select * from (
  select cast (
    json_array_elements(json_field::json->'columns') as text
  ) as column_data from table_name
) as temp
```

However, this just adds the content of the columns array to a single field.

How can I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use json_to_recordset

```
    SELECT  x.*
FROM pjson_table
   , json_to_recordset(myjson::json) x 
        (  nested_key_1 text
         , nested_key_2 text         
        )
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.